# Javascript - everything is out of scope

Tags: javascript

So, I have this code:

```js
<script>

    //We'll pass you an array of two numbers. 
    //Return the sum of those two numbers plus the sum of all the numbers 
    //between them. 
    //The lowest number will not always come first.
    function sumAll(arr) {

        var number1 = arr[0];
        var number2 = arr[1];

        var lower_number;
        var bigger_number;


        if (number2 < number1) {
            number2 = lower_number;
            number1 = bigger_number;

        } else {
            number1 = lower_number;
            number2 = bigger_number;

        }
        var i;

        var something;

        for (i = lower_number; i < bigger_number; i++) {

            something = i + something;
            console.log(i);

        }
        return something;
    }
    sumAll([1, 4]);
    sumAll([4, 1]);

</script>
```

This doesn't work. When I try to look in the console what are the results (like `i` or `something`), I just see `undefined` there.

Any suggestions please?

Also, how can I actually verify the result of the function? I am very new into `JS`.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't do anything with the returned values.

Comment: It also looks like you're assigning values backwards - `number2 = lower_number` instead of `lower_number = number2`

Comment: `something` should start as 0, so that numbers can be added to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log(i)` is showing `undefined` because that is the value of the variable. It's not a scope problem.

You never assigned anything to `lower_number`. So when you do `i = lower_number`, you're doing `i = undefined`, and that's what gets logged.

Actually, you should never even get into the loop, because `i < bigger_number` will always fail because `i` and `bigger_number` are both `undefined`, and `undefined < undefined` is false.

The reason is that your earlier assignments are backwards. This section:

```
    if (number2 < number1) {
        number2 = lower_number;
        number1 = bigger_number;
    } else {
        number1 = lower_number;
        number2 = bigger_number;
    }
```

should be:

```
    if (number2 < number1) {
        lower_number = number2;
        bigger_number = number1;
    } else {
        lower_number = number1;
        bigger_number = number2;
    }
```

Assignments are always in the order `destination = source;` (this is common to most programming languages).

You can verify the result of the function by logging the function call:

```
console.log(sumAll([1, 4]));
```